# Separate the repeated occurring elements and unique elements from a given array to two new arrays containing unique elements and recurring elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, data-structures

Would someone be able to assist me with this question?
Given an array of objects, we need to splits objects in an array that is repeating and non-repeating according to the **segments** into an *independent array*.
*for example*-

[ {name:"abc",id:1,segments:[1,2]}, {name:"abc1",id:2,segments:[1]}, {name:"abc3",id:3,segments:[1,2]},
{name:"abc2",id:4,segments:[1,2,3]} ]

the required **resultant array** is as follow -

uniqueArr = [{ name:"abc1",id:2,segments:[1]},{ name:"abc2",id:4,segments:[1,2,3]}]

- above example is for non-repeating objects in the given array

repeatedEle = [[{ name:"abc",id:1,segments:[1,2]},{ name:"abc3",id:3,segments:[1,2]}]]

- above example is for repeating objects in the given array according to number of occurence of same segments.
- Repeated elements must be inside a **nested array**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to separate arrays based on the segment prop?

Note: this in not a performance optimised solution but for small array this should be fine.

```js
const data = [
  {name:"abc",id:1,segments:[1,2]},
  {name:"abc1",id:2,segments:[1]},
  {name:"abc3",id:3,segments:[1,2]},
  {name:"abc2",id:4,segments:[1,2,3]},
];

const uniqueData = data.filter((entry, idx, originalArray) => {
  const copyArray = [...originalArray];
  copyArray.splice(idx, 1);
  
  return !copyArray.some((element) => entry.segments.sort().join() === element.segments.sort().join());
});

const nonUniqueData = data.filter((entry) => !uniqueData.includes(entry));

console.log({uniqueData, nonUniqueData});
```

Here is another solution.

```js
const data = [
  {name:"abc",id:1,segments:[1,2]},
  {name:"abc1",id:2,segments:[1]},
  {name:"abc3",id:3,segments:[1,2]},
  {name:"abc2",id:4,segments:[1,2,3]},
];

const segmentedData = data.reduce((acc, entry, idx, src) => {

  const copyArray = [...src];
  copyArray.splice(idx, 1);
  
  const key = copyArray.some((element) => entry.segments.sort().join() === element.segments.sort().join()) ? 'nonunique' : 'unique';
  
  acc[key].push(entry);
  
  return acc;

}, { unique: [], nonunique: [] });

console.log(segmentedData);
```

Comment: This solution is working fine for me. Thanks for your help.